# Can't Resolve Android Resource Strings

Tags: android, string

I am learning Android, and I have what I think is a weird problem.

in /res/values/strings.xml I have:

```
<string name="titleStatus">Status Update</string>
```

in /res/layout/activity_status.xml I have:

```
<!-- Title TextView-->
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
  android:textSize="30sp"
  android:layout_margin="10dp" android:text="@string/titleStatus"/>
```

However, when viewing activity_status.xml I am getting error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with
>   value '@string/titleStatus'). activity_status.xml

I then figured it could possibly help use "Project | Clean", but I get the same problem (and now without the auto-generated R.java class)

I am following this tutorial/book: 
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449390501/Android_User_Interface.html

Comment: Press `ctrl-shift-s` and try cleaning again. Maybe you haven't saved your strings.xml

Comment: It appears this might have solved it. I noticed after doing that followed by clean and builds the R file was regenerated ad looked correct. And then errors stopped as well.

Comment: That seems about right. Whenever you add something to a resource file and try to use it in another without saving it first, you will get an error. The normal `ctrl+s` just saves the file you're in, so compilation will occur without the new resources in the other file.

Comment: Thanks! Ïf I could, I would mark your comment as the accepted solution/answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you add something to a resource file and try to use it in another without saving it first, you will get an error.

The normal `ctrl+s` just saves the file you're in, so compilation will occur without the changes in the other file.

Pressing `ctrl-shift-s` saves changes in all open files (same as going to `File -> Save All`).

Personally, I hit `ctrl-shift-o`, `ctrl-shift-f` and `ctrl-shift-s` everytime I need to save some changes to organize the imports, format the code to fix indenting etc. and to save all changes.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Android Studio.
Select: File -->> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
Solved it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your R file is not generated correctly. Can you look at the build errors(if any) by eclipse. If not verify your R file is generated correctly and the entry titleStatus is in it

Comment: The problem now is that the R file is no longer even generated because of the error above. (If I recall correctly, I did check the R file before I tried clearning, and it wasn't in at the time.)

Comment: Check the Console in Eclipse and Error messages. Sometimes eclipse is a bit buggy and dosent show it explicitly, but R not being generated could be a result of an error in one of your XML files.