# DrawableLeft fails to compile

Tags: android, button, drawable, stock

I currently have a code for a button in XML as such:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
    android:text="Start Slideshow" />
```

However, I get an error for `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawableLeft' with value '@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow').`  However, when I check on the graphical layout of the XML file, the stock drawable at `ic_menu_slideshow` is present.  Why do I get this compilation error, and how would I fix it?

Comment: try cleaning and rebuilding the project!

Comment: `Cleaning happens to result in the same error, unfortunately.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow` with `@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried cleaning your project? A similar question was asked moments ago so keep an eye on that as well: [Can't Resolve Android Resource Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427890/cant-resolve-android-resource-strings)